# Automatically update .nupec file with dependencies

Tags: nuget-package

I've created a nuget package that is used by another project.

My package references `Microsoft.Identity.Web` version `1.23.1`. When I pull this package into the project where I want to you use it, I don't get told that my package has this dependency, I understand I can add the following to the .nuspec file to fix this:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Identity.Web" version="1.23.1" />
    </dependencies>
```

Now I'll get the message about also downloading this package when I install my own package.
I would like this to happen automatically, I don't want to have to go into here and update the version numbers and/or add any new dependencies when I update my package.

I'm sure there is a very basic answer to this but I just can't seem to find the answer.

My .csproj for my package:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.23.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update=".nuspec">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to not use a nuspec at all - they're a bit legacy, and since you're using `PackageReference` dotnet can get all the info it needs from your project file.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target for how to use your project file to specify any other values you've currently got in your nuspec